# How do I clear stale entries in ipython's Notebook list?

Tags: python, sqlite, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I run `ipython notebook list` from the command line, I am supposed to get a list of currently running notebook servers; but somehow some entries remain after I shut down a server. Having failed to find a session list file in `~/.ipython`, I dug around in the source (`sessionmanager.py`) and found that sessions get looked up in an sqlite database:

```
def list_sessions(self):
    """Returns a list of dictionaries containing all the information from
    the session database"""
    c = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM session")
    return list(c.fetchall())
```

Great, let's find the database and zap it. But the database appears to get initialized like this:

```
self._connection = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
```

That's right, it's an in-memory database that should disappear when the process shuts down. But I've shut down every single python or notebook process I had running, and yet the zombie sessions still appear. Does anyone here understand the system well enough to explain how they stick around, and/or how to get rid of them?  (I'm on OS X, if that matters).

Comment: I don't and have not had any notebooks running but I still have a long  list of `Currently running servers:`

Comment: Righto... so how does it do it????

Comment: using `sudo netstat -tapen | grep ":8890"` shows nothing is actually listening on the port though

Comment: If you want to remove them from the list, on ubuntu it is `/home/user/.ipython/profile_default/security`, you will see /home/padraic/.ipython/profile_default/security/ files like `nbserver-13578.json` delete them  and you will see an empty list when you check again

Comment: Awesome, thanks for sorting it out! Please put that in an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: no worries, I will put an answer together in a min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove them from the list, on `ubuntu` it is under:
 `/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/security`

You will see files like `nbserver-13578.json`  which are created each time you launch a new `notebook`, if you delete them you should see an empty list when you check again using:

`ipython notebook list`

```
  Currently running servers:
  :~$
```

Comment: Super, thanks. It's the same place on OS X (and on any Unix system, I suspect).

Comment: Yep, it will be `~/.ipython/profile_default/security/` on any system, unless it's overridden by the `IPYTHONDIR` environment variable. The notebook server should remove its nbserver file when it shuts down, but if it doesn't shut down cleanly, the file will be left around.